# UIPageViewController slide show for given interval

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

Like to design an app with pageview controller that automatically move pages for certain time interval.

I tried with timer, that set viewcontroller for every n seconds using below method

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([contentViewControllerToDisplay],
                                                direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
                                                animated: true,
                                                completion: nil)
```

Is there any inbuilt properties/ methods available to achieve this without using timer?

Comment: see this http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/

Comment: No, It's not possible and there is no method to achieve this. Timer is the only way right now